# Python: pandas DataFrame new column based on other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `df` with 2 columns like below:

```py
        A       B
0  100-00     nan
1  200-00     nan
2   other  300-00
3  100-00    text
4   other     nan
```

I need to create column C which will apply logic as below:

- if B is nan, then A
- if B starts with numeric, then B
- else A

I've got code as below, which is working just fine, but I believe there might be a better, more efficent way to do it:

```py
C = []
for r in range(df.shape[0]):
    if df['B'].iloc[r] == 'nan':
        C.append(df['A'].iloc[r])
    elif df['B'].iloc[r][:3].isnumeric():
        C.append(df['B'].iloc[r])
    else:
        C.append(df['A'].iloc[r])
df['C'] = C

df
        A       B       C
0  100-00     nan  100-00
1  200-00     nan  200-00
2   other  300-00  300-00
3  100-00    text  100-00
4   other     nan   other
```

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I simplify solution for `df.B` if first character in `df.B` is numeric tested with [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with regex `^` for start of string and `\d` for number in [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['C'] = np.where(df['B'].str.contains(r'^\d', na=False), df.B, df.A)
#alternative
#df['C'] = df.B.where(df['B'].str.contains(r'^\d', na=False), df.A)
print (df)
        A       B       C
0  100-00     NaN  100-00
1  200-00     NaN  200-00
2   other  300-00  300-00
3  100-00    text  100-00
4   other     NaN   other
```

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily more efficient, but a more pythonic way to do it

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['100-00', '200-00', 'other', '100-00', 'other'], 'B': ['nan', 'nan', '300-00', 'text', 'nan']})

def label_columnC(row):
    if row['B'] == 'nan':
        return row['A']
    elif row['B'][:3].isnumeric():
        return row['B']
    else:
        return row['A']

df['C'] = df.apply(lambda row: label_columnC(row), axis=1)
```